# MVC 6 [Authorize(Roles = "*")] Simple Example

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to get authentication and authorization working with the latest version of asp.net 5.

Are there simple examples of what needs to be added to Startup.cs to wire this capability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](http://leastprivilege.com/2015/10/12/the-state-of-security-in-asp-net-5-and-mvc-6-authorization/) covers it off quite nicely.

Essentially, `[Authorize(Roles = "Blah")]` is only there for backwards compatability and policies is the way forward.

I'm not going to cut and paste it, but essentially, for this action:

```
[Authorize("SalesOnly")]
public IActionResult DoSalesyStuff()
{ /* .. */ }
```

Wired in Startup.ConfigureServices:

```
// only allow authenticated users
var defaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
    .Build();

services.AddMvc(setup =>
{
    setup.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(defaultPolicy));
});

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // inline policies
    options.AddPolicy("SalesOnly", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireClaim("department", "sales"); // Some policy
    });
});
```

The author has put their [full example code on github](https://github.com/leastprivilege/AspNet5AuthorizationPlayground) and the source for the [security middleware is here](https://github.com/aspnet/security).